# Pause an AWS Workflow, Resume after a set time

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have an AWS workflow containing three glue jobs. I want to have a pause of 2 hours after a job completion.
After 2 hours, workflow should Resume the process. Is there a way we can achieve this?